# Purchasing Landscape

Tags: server, canonical, landscape, ubuntu-advantage

My organisation is interested in purchasing Ubuntu Advantage Essential Server, in order to use Landscape. But I have filled every forms I have found on Canonical's web site and on their "shop", and did not get any reply. This has been during a few weeks.

The delay in my work is getting very problematic, so please, can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure how this falls within the on-topic scope, but I would recommend contacting them directly via any phone or emails you have for contacting them.

Comment: askubuntu.com isn't affiliated with Canonical. We're just a community of individuals who ask and answer questions related to Ubuntu and Ubuntu's software

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry you had such a difficult time. If you contact us (http://www.ubuntu.com/management/contact-us) we'll get in touch with you and make sure to get you sorted. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Already filled this form 3 or 4 time.